# Getting output of one scenario as input to another scenario in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I am using cucumber in combination with selenium for testing the java web application. The following is the Scenario that we have

```
get generate PIN page
enter user name 
enter password 
click on submit button
```

Now it generates a PIN in the database depending on so many calculations. now i need that particular PIN, to give it as an input to a different scenario. how can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you can access the PIN within the database after the above scenario. That being the case, I would add one more step to the scenario that acquires - and confirms - that the PIN was indeed generated. At that point, you can store the PIN in a local variable and then use it within the next scenario.

So your first scenario would look like this:

```
Get generate PIN page
Enter user name
Enter password
Click on submit button
Confirm PIN number in database
```

The last step would not be done within Selenium, but via an API call or some other means to acquire the PIN from the database. It would confirm the PIN (e.g.; `regex=/^\d{4}$/`) and then store it in a local variable, say something like `@customer_pin` (assuming you're using Ruby).

Your next scenario would start off something like this:

```
Get generate login page
Enter customer ID
Enter customer PIN
etc
```

When you hit the "Enter customer PIN" step, you pull it from the locally stored variable (`@customer_pin`).

My advice is that when executing this second scenario, you confirm that you have a legitimate PIN within your locally stored variable, in case someone should run this scenario out of sequence. You could do this by using a global variable and running a "Before" hook in your `features/support/env.rb` file like this:

```
Before do
  $dunit ||= false
  return if $dunit
  $customer_pin = nil
  $dunit = true
end
```

In this case, I use `$customer_pin` instead of `@customer_pin` in order to make the variable globally accessible. Then after running your first scenario, `$customer_pin` would be assigned to a legitimate value so that it can be used in any subsequent scenarios. Subsequent scenarios would use the regex expression to confirm it has a legitimate value, and raise/throw an exception if not.

Comment: Your suggestion is based on the execution order of scenarios and relying on  the success of a scenario. I would advice against assuming an execution order and expecting a success from other scenarios. It is a well known anti-pattern.

Comment: In general I agree, but like most things in life ... it depends. The above case may be a poor example of a good excuse to break a programming pattern, so your concern is well received. But sometimes I do break patterns in the spirit of the greater good. For example, running smaller tests as stepping stones for bigger tests can be more expedient and less invasive than repeating the background setups for every test.

Answer (score 0):

I would divide your problem into two.

One that verifies the pin generation as this may be important for your stakeholders.

One that implement a backdoor to support other cases where a valid PIN is needed. Maybe an API that is able to generate or retrieve a valid pin number. Maybe create and store the PIN in the database without touching the system from the outside. I would use this way to retrieve a PIN whenever I need a valid PIN for other scenarios.

The technical solution on how to get a valid PIN isn't too important. What is important is to decouple the execution order of the scenarios. The execution order of the scenarios is undefined. Each scenario must be able to be executed in isolation and in random order.

Coupling scenarios is a well known anti pattern described [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/cucumber-podcast-rss/id1078896635) and [here](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2016/06/22/cucumber-antipatterns).

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this kind of situation you have to use Cucumber **Background** feature, This is run before each step. and will generate a PIN based on given inputs and then generated PIN will be available across the scenarios.

Find feature file definition based on your requirements.

```
Background: 
    Given   I Get generate PIN page
    Then    I Enter user name
    And     Enter password 
    And     I Click on submit button
    And     I Confirm PIN number in database


@TC01_GetUserInformationByPinTest @NoBrowser 
Scenario: Get User information by generated PIN from background. 
    Given  I Get User Information by using generated PIN
    And    I verified that given username is same as response Data
```

I believe this will help you to solve your issue.